# Swift: Modify array of UIButtons through pass by reference

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview

**Problem:** Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'cardView' is a 'let' constant

**Solution 1 that I found (but with unwanted behavior):**
Code works fine when I just skip the inout declarations and "&". But the view doesn't get updated immediately.

```
// Line 3: updateCardView(...) is producing the error   
private func updateViewFromModel() {
        ...
        for (index, cardView) in cardsContainerView.cardViews.enumerated() {
            updateCardView(game.handedOutCards[index], &cardView)       
        }
  }

   private func updateCardView (_ card: Card, _ cardView: inout CardView)  {
       cardView.layerState(cardView: &cardView)
       cardView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor
  }


class CardsContainerView: UIView {
    var cardViews = [CardView](){
    didSet {
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

class CardView: UIButton {
     func layerState(cardView: inout CardView) {
         cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
         cardView.layer.borderWidth = 2 
     }
 }
```

**Solution 2 working but only when layerState() is empty:**

```
private func updateViewFromModel() {
     ...
     for index in cardsContainerView.cardViews.indices {
         updateCardView(game.handedOutCards[index], cardsContainerView.cardViews[index])       
     }
}

private func updateCardView (_ card: Card, _ cardView: CardView)  {
    cardView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cardView.layerState()
    cardView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor
}


class CardsContainerView: UIView {
    var cardViews = [CardView](){
    didSet {
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

class CardView: UIButton {
     func layerState() {
         // Setting a border within this function is not working as expected
         // The borders of the cards are only shown after another touch event and only for old objects of cardViews
         //self.layer.borderWidth = 2
     }
 }
```

**Expected result**:
Every new button should have a border displayed immediately after it was created and the view was updated. The border parameters should be set within `layerState()`.

**Actual result:**
When setting a borderWidth within `layerState()` no border is shown immediately. However, after another touch event already existing instances of `cardView` have a border as expected.

Comment: You need to call `cardView.layerState()` from `updateCardView`.  `layerState()` doesn't need to take an argument.  `self` is the `cardView` is setting.

Comment: You are right, I have fixed the issues above, sorry about that. What do you mean with `self` is the `cardView` is setting?

Answer (score 3):

`cardView` is a `let` constant because it is created by the `for` loop.  You could make it a `var` by adding the `var` keyword:

```
for (index, var cardView) in cardsContainerView.cardViews.enumerated() {
    updateCardView(game.handedOutCards[index], &cardView)       
}
```

But that is kind of a mess, because you are still creating a new variable that is a reference to the one in the array, and then passing that variable.  It works because both the variable in the array and the new variable are references to your card object, but the whole `inout` thing is a waste because you are just tossing the `cardView` copy in the next iteration of the loop.

You could change your loop to:

```
for index in cardsContainerView.cardViews.indices {
    updateCardView(game.handedOutCards[index], &cardsContainerView.cardViews[index])       
}
```

Here, you are using `index` to find and pass the value directly from the array, so the array item will then be updated.  This would even work if `cardView` were a `struct` instead of a `class`.

Since you're working with a `class` though, you can update the objects without using `inout`.

---

You should be using `self` to update the object instead of using `inout` to pass in the reference:

```
class CardView: UIButton {
     func layerState() {
         self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
         self.layer.borderWidth = 2 
     }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `cardView.setNeedsDisplay()` after updating the cardViews is they aren't displaying properly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I removed all inout and use this in the for loop: `updateCardView(game.handedOutCards[index], cardView)`. However, the behaviour remains the same and the cards get blue after another touch event and when `updateViewFromModel` is again executed. Unfortunately,`cardView.setNeedsDisplay()` doesn't change this behaviour.

Comment: I found a workaround: When I add `cardView.layer.borderWidth = 2` at the end of `updateCardView` then the borders are blue immediately as expected. However, how can I reach the same behaviour through calling `cardView.layerState()`?

Comment: What happens if you set `self.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral...` in `layerState()` before setting the `borderWidth`?

Comment: When I add `self.layer.borderColor = ...` to `layerState()` nothing changes. The positioning of `borderWidth` doesn't have an effect. However, I think that the problem is somehow in the `layerState` method. I'm not an expert but isn't the for loop passing a copy (since it's an element of an array) of UIButton to `updateCardView(...)`. Then `cardView.layerState()` modifies this copy and in a row, when the copy is released from memory, the original gets changed as well. But I don't know how to solve that tricky puzzle.

Comment: `cardView` is a reference to a `CardView` object.  `layerState()` is updating the object itself.  Your `for` loop doesn't have a copy of a `UIButton`, it has another `reference` to the `UIButton`.  Only a single `UIButton` exists in this case and both the `cardView` loop variable and the array point to it.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation! What else could be the cause that the border is not shown when it's being set in `layerState()`?

Comment: Are you calling `updateViewFromModel()` from a background thread? If so, you need to switch to the main thread for UI updates.

Comment: It's just a simple one page demo app. So ùpdateViewFromModel()` gets called in the main ViewController after `viewDidLoad` or a touchEvent of a button. However, for me it's still unclear why everything works fine when I directly call `cardView.layer.borderWidth = 2` within `updateCardView()`. And it stops working when `self.layer.borderWidth = 2` is called in `layerState()`.

Comment: Edit your question to include all of your current code so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: We need to see all of your code so that we can reproduce your issue.  It is not clear how you are adding a button.  If `updateViewFromModel()` is only called when a button is pressed, why would you expect new buttons to appear with a border?